# Custom Mongoose Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web, mongoose, schema

I would like to create a custom Mongoose Schema.

I have a json file such as

```
{
  "year": 2016,
  "day": 306
}
```

And my Schema is

```
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var FluxSchema = new Schema({
    year: { type: Number },
    day: { type: Number }})
```

I have a function that converts day 306 to 2016/11/01. I would like to know if I could create a custom schema which would automatically call this function once a data is inserted in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can import Your schema and use .save method.
For example:

```
var FluxSchema = require('path/to/schema/fluxSchema'),
    yourJSON = require('path/to/yourjson.json');
// ...some other code
var flux = new FluxSchema({
            year: yourJSON.year,
            day: yourJSON.day
        });
flux.save(function(err){
    if(err) throw err;
    // Your convertion code
});
```